# React JS- else block is not executing inside Map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am implementing a notification where every 10 secs I am making an api call and based on the response received, I am displaying the notification alert. The issue I am facing here is div is not getting rendered.I am displaying the div based on some condition inside my map function.
Here, the data is array of objects which I am getting as a response of an api call.For some reasons, I am seeing the else part is never getting executed and I am always getting the div mentioned in if block. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. item.description value will vary based on the logged in user.

```
getNotificationDetails = (data) =>{ 
    const payloadData = data.payLoad && data.payLoad.map(item => {
                if (item.description == generatedStatus){
                    return 
                    (
                        <div key = {item.id} className="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible show" role="alert">
                              You have received notification
                            <Link  to='/validated'> {item.extendedAccessKey} </Link>
                            <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" onClick={this.updateNotification}>
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>  
                    )
                } else {
                    return 
                    (
                        <div key = {item.id} className="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible show" role="alert">
                              Your detail has been shared with
                            <Link to='/validated'> {item.extendedAccessKey} </Link>
                            <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" onClick={this.updateNotification}>
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>  
                    )
                }
            })
            return payloadData;
            console.log(payloadData);

        }
render() { 
        const data = this.props.getNotificationStatus;
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.payLoad);
        const isAccessKeyLinked = Object.keys((data.length === 0))

        return (  
            <div className="notification-alert">
                    {
                        (!isAccessKeyLinked)
                        ?
                        (this.state.isActive  && this.getNotificationDetails(data))
                        :
                        (this.state.isActive  && this.getNotificationDetails(data))
                    }


            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: What is `data` when you log it in `render()`? Is it possible you need `const data = this.props.getNotificationStatus();`?

Comment: is this is a state full component  ?

Comment: data is an array of object that I am getting it from my store

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS yes.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I had written that before then changed it thinking its an array of object so data.length should work.

Comment: @techiequestie  i have few doubts based on your question , getNotificationStatus is a method or its a variable where you hold the status value in redux?

Comment: getNotificationStatus its a variable where I am holding the states in redux

Comment: @techiequestie what is data consist of ?  even if its has length 0, why are you again passing it to the getNotificationStatus

Comment: data consists of array of multiple objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184814/discussion-between-dileep-thomas-and-techie-questie).

Answer (score 0):

Here `getNotificationDetails` is a functional component as it will return a view.

This `(this.state.isActive  && this.getNotificationDetails(data))` does not look valid, as one is Boolean value and other is a view.

And `console.log(payloadData);`  is called after return statement.